# Shorten a name and display correctly in html?

Tags: html, dom, multilingual

I have a site which have users who have a name in hebrew (rtl) and in english.

if name is in hebrew, the dot should display at the left side of the word like this:

.אדם ל

in english of course:

adam L.

When my site is in ltr mode, and hebrew name is shown, the dot is not in the right place, how should i shorten the name and display it correctly in the html if the name is in another language?

Comment: You could use regex to find '.' in a name and then rebuild the string by splicing the '.' from the end of the string and move it to the start, you would need Javascript for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use before and after with css:

```js
function changeLang(lang) {
  if (lang === 'he') {
    $('.name').addClass('rtl');
    // this is only for demonstration
    $('.name').html('אדם ל');
  } else {
    $('.name').removeClass('rtl');
    // this is only for demonstration
    $('.name').html('Mr David');
  }

}
```

```css
.name::after {
  content: '.';
}
.name.rtl::before {
  content: '.';
}
.name.rtl::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello <span class="name">Mr David</span>
    </h1>
<button onclick="changeLang('en')">English</button>
<button onclick="changeLang('he')">Hebrew</button>
```